# welcome-file tag seems to be ignored

Tags: struts2, maven, appfuse

based on struts2 appfuse maven project I am trying to set up my personal HelloWorld struts2 maven project.

I have simplified a lot of things in pom.xml, web.xml and struts.xml file. As a result of that, it seems that `<welcome-file-list>` and `<welcome-file>` tags are not getting into account, and when I hit http://localhost:8080/, my file index.jsp is not loaded.
Next error message appears:
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name .

(after word ‘name’, is a blank space)

Any comments will be appreciated.

Inside web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
             org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
            </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Inside struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default"> 
    <action name="Menu">
        <result>/menu/Menu.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: can you just show the error console output

Comment: # Messages:  There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name .
Stacktraces
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name . - [unknown location]

    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:178)

Comment: ok..This means there is some issue in your mapping and from where you are calling your action.Can you show us the jsp file from where you are calling the action "Menu"

Comment: Sorry, forgot for now the Menu action and other things. As I think, the problem is a step before; I just want my simple index.jsp welcome file to get loaded without intervention of Struts2 mechanisms.
(Inside index.jsp I only put the classical ‘Hello world!’ )

Comment: OK!! Den remove everything just create a dynamic web-application and check if index page is coming or not..Problem what you have mentioned is clear struts2 is unable to map the action to any location

Answer (score 0):

Seems struts2 filter is trying to find the action for the name empty "" or "/" path. So welcome list will not be reached. Also no entry in struts.xml for "" & "/". thats y getting this error.

so add the below entry in struts.xml will solve this issue..

```
<action name=""> <result>jsp file path</result></action>
<action name="/"> <result>jsp file path</result></action>
```